# HTTP POST to bytebin.lucko.me responds differently to python's requests than jquery's ajax. Why?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, python-requests

python code:

```
def callback(data):
    print(data)

requests.post(
        'https://bytebin.lucko.me/post',
        data='test',
        headers={'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
        hooks={'response': callback})
```

data printed is `< Response: 201 >`, a response object, when doing POST request with python's requests

javascript code:

```
function callback(data){
    console.log(data)
}
$.ajax("https://bytebin.lucko.me/post", {
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: 'test',
    method: "POST",
    success: callback,
    error: () => {

    }
});
```

data printed is `{'key': 'random alphanumeric'}`, the desired output

Why is the output different? I want the data with the `key` attribute when making a POST request in python

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a Response object back. Perhaps you want to print the `response.json()` instead?

```
>>> print(requests.post('https://bytebin.lucko.me/post', 'test').json())
{u'key': u'WZsV5YOLSu'}
```